# How to use HashSet<string>.Contains() method in case -insensitive mode?

Tags: c#, string, hashset

How to use `HashSet<string>.Contains()` method in case -insensitive mode?

Comment: One sidenode: when a 'normal' `HashSet<string>` (case sensitive) is created, it's impossible to create a `contains` method that is efficient. This because the hashes of the elements are created when they are added to the `HashSet`. And internally the `contains` method checks the hashes to be efficient. It's not possible to (efficiently) convert an existing hash form 'case sensitive' to 'case insensitive'.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

You can create the `HashSet` with a custom comparer:

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

hs.Add("Hello");

Console.WriteLine(hs.Contains("HeLLo"));
```

Comment: +1 Because you use `Ordinal` instead of `InvariantCulture`. The .NET guidelines advice us not to use `InvariantCulture` in most cases (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx).

Comment: CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is usually the better choice.

Comment: mdsdn says:
Use StringComparison.Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase for comparisons as your safe default for culture-agnostic string matching.

Comment: I believe CurrentCultureIgnoreCase will fail the "Turkey Test".  "LIST" and "list" will fail to match if the current culture is Turkey, as the lower case of "I" in that culture is not "i" but instead is "ı" without a dot.  So if you expect "LIST" == "list" you will be disappointed that if current culture is turkey, then that will return false.  If the strings you are comparing are not string in the user's language, I.e. **If they are some sort of strings that have nothing to do with the user's language, then use InvariantCultureIgnoreCase**

Comment: Can't edit, but true that OrdinalIgnoreCase is usually preferred over InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.  I just wanted to point out why CurrentCultureIgnoreCase is probably not applicable(but depends on if it is a string relevant to the user's language or not).

Answer (score 10):

You need to create it with the right `IEqualityComparer`:

```
HashSet<string> hashset = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessary here, as other answers have demonstrated, but in other cases where you are not using a string, you can choose to implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` and then you can use a `.Contains` overload. Here is an example using a string (again, other answers have shown that there is already a string comparer you can use that meets your needs). Many methods surrounding `IEnumerable<T>` have overloads that accept such comparers, so it's good to learn how to implement them.

```
class CustomStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        return x.Equals(y, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then use it

```
bool contains = hash.Contains("foo", new CustomStringComparer());
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359100.aspx) which allows you to specify the `IEqualityComparer` you want to use.

```
HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The [StringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer_members.aspx) object provides some often used comparer as static properties.