# Make HashSet<string> case-insensitive

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I have method with HashSet parameter. And I need to do case-insensitive Contains within it:

```
public void DoSomething(HashSet<string> set, string item)
{
    var x = set.Contains(item);
    ... 
}
```

Is it any way to make existing HashSet case-insensitive (do not create new one)?

I'm looking for solution with best perfomance.

**Edit**

Contains can be called multiple times. So IEnumerable extensions are not acceptable for me due to lower perfomance than native HashSet Contains method.

**Solution**

Since, answer to my question is NO, it is impossible, I've created and used following method:

```
public HashSet<string> EnsureCaseInsensitive(HashSet<string> set)
{
    return set.Comparer == StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
           ? set
           : new HashSet<string>(set, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have to create a new one...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667635/how-to-use-hashsetstring-contains-method-in-case-insensitive-mode (see user414076's answer)

Comment: You need to decide up front whether or not the `HashSet` considers case by supplying a comparer. However, it's worth considering that the set {"A","a"} will only contain one item with a case-insensitive comparer.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The `HashSet<T>` constructor has an overload that lets you pass in a custom `IEqualityComparer<string>`. There are a few of these defined for you already in the static `StringComparer` class, a few of which ignore case. For example:

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
set.Add("john");
Debug.Assert(set.Contains("JohN"));
```

You'll have to make this change at the time of constructing the `HashSet<T>`.  Once one exists, you can't change the `IEqualityComparer<T>` it's using.

---

Just so you know, by default (if you don't pass in any `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the `HashSet<T>` constructor), it uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` instead.

---

## Edit

The question appears to have changed after I posted my answer.  If you have to do a case *insensitive* search in an existing case *sensitive* `HashSet<string>`, you will have to do a linear search:

```
set.Any(s => string.Equals(s, item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

There's no way around this.

Comment: If you are doing a single lookup - this is worse than just looping across the hashset

Comment: @DaveBish I believe the OP changed his question to say "do not create new one" after I had answered... (edits very soon after posting don't actually count as edits). - If the OP has to do this with *an existing* `HashSet<T>`, then of course he will have to do a linear time search.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. If he is only doing one lookup against the hashset - creating a new one is more costly than a linear scan. (Op didn't specify)

Comment: @DaveBish That's exactly why I edited my answer to include the LINQ linear scan. :)

Comment: Here is an alternative, but I would prefer **a clearer LINQ solution above**. You can use `Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)` like this: `set.Contains(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. It will perform generally the same linear search, though Resharper will generate a "Possibly unintended linear search in set" warning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't using `new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` result in the possibility that you could have two items with different case be in the set?  Comparison is only done after jumping to the bucket where the hash points to.  Therefore, wouldn't 'a' and 'A' potentially point to different buckets and therefore not discover that there is already another item that is the same and then add it to the set?

Answer (score 11):

You can not magically make case-sensetive HashSet (or Dictionary) to behave in case-insensitive way.

You have to recreate one inside your function if you can not rely on incoming `HashSet` to be case-insensitive.

Most compact code - use [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503873.aspx) from existing set:

```
var insensitive = new HashSet<string>(
   set, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Note that copying `HashSet` is as expensive as walking through all items, so if your function does just on search it would be cheaper (O(n)) to iterate through all items. If your function called multiple times to make single case-insensitive search you should try to pass proper `HashSet` to it instead.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you've got this extension method:

```
public static HashSet<T> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(source);
}
```

You can just use this:

```
set = set.Select(n => n.ToLowerInvariant()).ToHashSet();
```

Or, you could just do this:

```
set = new HashSet(set, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
//or InvariantCultureIgnoreCase or CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
```

Comment: If you are doing a single lookup - this is worse than just looping across the hashset

Comment: It would grab a lot of memory and do a lot of hash calculations, then throw all that work away after one lookup. Looping over the whole hash set and doing case-insensitive comparisons runs in constant memory and doesn't have to calculate hashes. Both need to touch the entirety of `set` in any case.

Comment: Because making a new hashset will at-least have to loop over the whole thing!

Comment: @DaveBish The most upvoted answer also happens to do that... it needs to reconstruct it as well...

Comment: I posted on that one, too :)

Answer (score 4):

The `HashSet` is designed to quickly find elements as per its hashing function and equality comparator. What you are asking for is really to find an element matching "some other" condition. Imagine that you have a `Set<Person>` objects that uses only `Person.Name` for comparison and you need to find an element with some given value of `Person.Age`.

The point is you need to iterate over the contents of the set to find the matching elements. If you are going to be doing this often you might create a different Set, in you case using a case-insensitive comparator but then you would have to make sure that this shadow set is in sync with the original.

The answers so far are essentially variations of the above, I thought to add this to clarify the fundamental issue.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of `HashSet` can take an alternative `IEqualityComparer` that can override how equality is determined.  See the list of constructors [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb354549.aspx).

The class `StringComparer` contains a bunch of static instances of `IEqualityComparers` for strings.  Particularly, you're probably interested in `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hc8kytd.aspx) is the documentation of `StringComparer`.

Note that another constructor takes in an `IEnumerable`, so you can construct a new `HashSet` from your old one, but with the `IEqualityComparer`.

So, all together, you want to convert your `HashSet` as follows:

```
var myNewHashSet = new HashSet(myOldHashSet, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to leave the original, case-sensitive version in place, you could just query it with linq with case insensitivity:

```
var contains = set.Any(a => a.Equals(item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can now use

```cs
set.Contains(item, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

without needing to re-create you HashSet