# Comparing Case Insensitive strings in a List of Objects with a Hash

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of strings like this:

```
    List<string> excelList = new List<string>();
    excelList.Add("ZArA");  excelList.Add("CalviN"); excelList.Add("BaD ZAra");
```

And I create a `Hashset` from it like this:

```
var hashet = new HashSet<string>(excelList,StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

And then I have a list of `objects` of a `class` like this:

```
public class MyDbObjects
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

List<MyDbObjects> dbObjectses = new List<MyDbObjects>();

// call .add here to add some actual objects to it.
```

Ok now I want to make sure that **ALL** the string values in the **excelList** 
are **existent** in my class objects list of `dbObjectses`  as a FirstName or LastName and **DON'T CARE ABOUT CASE SENSITIVITY** . 
My code below works **BUT**  it does **NOT** handle **case sensitivity**. How do I add that to it?

```
    var allofThemExist = dbObjectses.All(x => hashet.Contains(x.FirstName) || hashet.Contains(x.LastName));
```

Comment: I think your code doesn't match the text? You said "all string values in excelList exist in your class objects", but you check that all the values in your class objects exist in excelList

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922435/make-hashsetstring-case-insensitive)?

Comment: Maybe you can use `.Any(y=> string.Equals(y, x.FirstName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))` instead of `.Contains` and the same for `LastName`

Comment: Why do you think your code doesn't handle case sensitivity? The `HashSet`'s comparer is case insensitive, so its `.Contains` method will be case insensitive.

Comment: @Andy I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. He already has a `HashSet` which uses `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnorecase`.

Comment: @canton7  yep, I applied what I could from those other links ... but now stuck in the case sensitive part... not a duplicate.

Comment: @Bohn I'm with John - I don't think the problem is where you think it is. If you post a [mcve], we can investigate for ourselves.

Comment: By the way [the case insensitivity works great](https://rextester.com/JYU69930).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var hasAll = !excelList.Except(
                dbObjectses.Select(x => x.FirstName).Concat(
                dbObjectses.Select(x => x.LastName)), 
              StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Any();
```

`Except` uses hashtables internally so should have good performance.

Comment: would this handle edge cases if for example LastName property on one of the objects is NULL too ?

Comment: I would imagine that null would only equate with null.

Comment: @Bohn If excelList contains a null value it will require a null value to be in either FirstName or LastName in dbObjectses

Comment: @Magnus sorry I meant if NULL is in dbObjectses  properties ... just to make sure it won't crash

Comment: @Bohn It wont. But if I were you I would test it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

instrad of hasset, use the excelList,

```
var allofThemExist = dbObjectses.All(x => excelList.Contains(x.FirstName) || excelList.Contains(x.LastName));
```

Comment: nop, we want the REVERSE logic.  Making sure whatever is in excel list, also exists in dbOjects list

Comment: @Bohn it's almost like your faulty logic was the problem, and not the case sensitivity of the HashSet. Then again you said you ran the code and that's how you know the HashSet the problem, so I assume Uzair's logic is fine since you've decided it's the HashSet.